# Stub a function that runs a promise

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, sinon, aws-amplify

I've been attempting to write unit tests for a registration page on a new react application

However I am very new to the concept of Sinon stubs/spies and have been having issues with intercepting a function call and forcing a resolve.

This is my initial test:

```
test('Success notification is displayed if all information is valid', () => {
  wrapper.setState({ username: 'test', password: 'Test1234!@', confirmPassword: 'Test1234!@' });
  const stub = sinon.stub(Register.prototype, 'signUp').resolves('Test');
  wrapper.find('#submitRegistration').simulate('click');
});
```

onClick runs this event handler: (Simplified)

```
public onSubmitHandler(e: React.FormEvent) {
  // Perform password match check
  if (password === confirmPassword) {
      this.signUp(this.state.username, password);
    } else {
      // Set success state
    }
  } else {
    // Set error state
  }
}
```

And finally, Signup:

```
public signUp(username: string, password: string) {
  // Perform Cognito Signup
  return Auth.signUp({
    password,
    username,
  })
    .then(() => {
      // Set success State
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // Set error state
    });
}
```

How can I intercept the call to signUp and force it down the resolve path, Currently due to the fact i do not configure my AWS Amplify Auth module it catches every time with "No userPool"

Comment: I am assuming `Auth` is a module you import?

Comment: Yeah, Module imported from aws-amplify

Comment: Could you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Jest provides many ways of mocking out dependencies, primarily there are 2 flavours:

1. [Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) - These let you control mocks in far more details.
2. [Mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) - If you need a simple mock for a common problem, translation for example, these are very helpful.

For your case, you will also need to handle `Promises`, for this reason, you need to follow the advice on [testing async behaviour](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async).

For your case, I am assuming:

1. Auth is a module named 'auth-module'
2. you just need to setup the mock once and have 1 test data which resolves to success and 1 for failure.

```js
// telling jest to mock the entire module
    jest.mock("auth-module", () => ({
      // telling jest which method to mock
      signUp: ({ password, username }) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // setting the test expectations / test data
          process.nextTick(
            () =>
              username === "SuccessUser"
                ? resolve(userName)
                : reject({
                    error: "failure message"
                  })
          );
        })
    }));
```

*Note* : Adding the snippet even though it will not run, as the formatting seems to be broken with code block.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet
I ended up using your train of thought however slightly differently

Answer (score 0):

With a little thought push from dubes' answer I managed to get the following:

```
const signUpSpy = jest.spyOn(Auth, 'signUp').mockImplementation((user, password) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res();
  });
});
```

Instead of spying directly onto the function I wrote and call moved it to the Modules function and resolved the promise from there!